# Nullable property to entity field, Entity Framework through Code First

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, code-first, nullable

Using the data annotation `Required` like so:

```
[Required]
public int somefield {get; set;}
```

Will set **somefield** to `Not Null` in database, How can I set **somefield**
to allow NULLs?, I tried setting it through SQL Server Management Studio but Entity Framework set it back to *`Not Null`*.

Comment: I was actually searching to find out how to get CodeFirst to do NOT NULL and your question answered it perfectly!  Thanks :)

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Just omit the [Required] attribute from the `string somefield` property. This will make it create a `NULL`able column in the db.

To make int types allow NULLs in the database, they must be declared as nullable ints in the model:

```
// an int can never be null, so it will be created as NOT NULL in db
public int someintfield { get; set; }

// to have a nullable int, you need to declare it as an int?
// or as a System.Nullable<int>
public int? somenullableintfield { get; set; }
public System.Nullable<int> someothernullableintfield { get; set; }
```

Comment: In your question your property is a string. To make an int allow nulls, you have to declare it as a nullable int, like so: `public int? somenullableintfield { get; set; }`

Comment: Yes, my mistake, i need allow null to int types.

Comment: what about the situation (edge case, but one I am facing), the attributes are used for business rule validation and ease of use with mvc, but need to allow user to save partially completed forms (i.e. long forms that may take a while to do).  I need to be able to allow EF to create columns that allow nulls.. guessing its the modebuilder used in oncreating, but don't know how

Comment: what happen if you put [Required] on a nullable property like "public int? somenullableintfield { get; set; }"?

Comment: @AXMIM...a little late...but [Required] data annotation overrides int?.

Comment: @danludwig I made a class where there is no required but in the DB it is showing not null.

Comment: I believe as of C# 10, you will explicit have to add ? to string also, in order to have mssql server table display checkmark under 'allow nulls'. 
Hence a string property would have to look like: public string? name {get; set;}

Answer (score 38):

The other option is to tell EF to allow the column to be null:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        modelBuilder.Entity<SomeObject>().Property(m => m.somefield).IsOptional();            
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

This code should be in the object that inherits from `DbContext`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. This solved my problem with [Required] strings, allowing them to be null in the db, but enforcing a requirement in MVC helpers

Comment: Why don't you use ViewModels? Than it could be required in the viewmodel and not required in the real model.

Comment: it might be part of the model and viewmodel, but an optional field based on some business logic. danludwig's answer is the more complete solution (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10710934/6486)

Answer (score 21):

In ***Ef .net core*** there are two options that you can do; first with data annotations:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; } // optinal case

    [Required]
    public string Url { get; set; } // required case
}
```

Or with fluent api:

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
            .Property(b => b.Url)
            .IsRequired(false)//optinal case
            .IsRequired()//required case
            ;
    }
}

public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

There are more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/required-optional)

Comment: In the case of EF Core this is the answer that works.

Comment: Which is reflect the nullable, can you elaborate please?

Comment: @SuatAtanPhD .IsRequired(false) makes that column nullable if you don't set false as a input parameter than it is required, like .IsRequired()

Answer (score 4):

Jon's answer didn't work for me as I got a compiler error *CS0453  C# The type must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method*

This worked for me though:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<SomeObject>().HasOptional(m => m.somefield);
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: This is because you have defined the integer value as 'int' instead of 'int?'