# Nullable<double> field will force a Required client side validation to be On

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have created the following validation class :-

```
public class ProcessotInfo_Validation
    {

        public Nullable<double> SPEED { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But currently by default the field will be required, and I am unable to submit the form unless I enter a vale fo th SPEED field. Can anyone advice what is wrong ?

The field on the view is rendered using the following code:-

```
<div >
    <span class="f">CPU Speed (In MHz)  </span> 

   @Html.EditorFor(model =>model.SystemInfo.ProcessorInfoes.FirstOrDefault().SPEED)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.SystemInfo.ProcessorInfoes.FirstOrDefault().SPEED)

</div>
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is the answer or not but you can use DataAnnotations to mark a field as not being required. Does that help with what you are tying?

Comment: but i am trying to figure out why it is marked as Required. and which data annotation i can use to mark the field as not required?

Answer (score -2):

read it 
[Nullable property to entity field, Entity Framework through Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710393/nullable-property-to-entity-field-entity-framework-through-code-first)

Comment: Err... have you read what you've typed? You've suggested creating a nullable int called 'double' and missed a bracket. 

BTW: Nullable<double> and double? are exactly the same, so I think what you might have been asking him to do still wouldn't help