# LINQ SUM Nullable

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a simple linq query

```
(From a In db.payments Group Join b In db.interestcharges On  a.pid Equals b.pid Into totalinterest = Group, TotalInterestReceived = Sum(b.interest)) select a, TotalInterestReceived).toList()
```

`b.interest` is type decimal in DB.

Throws

```
"The cast to value type 'System.Decimal' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type."
```

This is because `InterestCharges` table may not have any interest records for `pid`.

I have tried   `sum(if(b.interest=nothing,0,b.interest)`  but this is translated by LINQ to `if(b.interest=0, 0, b.interest)` hence it never checks for null.  Nothing else seems to work instead of nothing. I have tried `vbNull`, `isDBNull()`, no success.  query works fine when the sum is not null. `defaultifempty(0)` may work but not sure how to use it in this scenario. Any pointers?

Comment: What is the type of b.interest?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Decimal

Comment: Does using Option Strict On give any useful hints to correct anything? Also, to compare to `Nothing`, the operator is `Is`, not `=`.

Comment: Cast `b.interest` here `Sum(b.interest)` to nullable `Decimal`, then apply conditional operator to assign 0 to `Sum(…)` result if null. In C# it would be `Sum((decimal?)b.interest) ?? 0`, I don't know the VB syntax, hope you could translate it.

Comment: @AndrewMorton  `is nothing` doesn't work in LINQ query, syntax error.

Comment: @IvanStoev compiler wouldn't allow cast from decimal to decimal?

Comment: @AllenKing Why not? Every value type `T` can be cast (converted) to `Nullable<T>`. This is from CLR, not language specific.

Comment: @IvanStoev I guess because `b.interest` is not nullable field in EntityFramework definitions hence compiler wouldn't allow it to be `DirectCast` to Decimal?

Comment: @AllenKing Perhaps one of the answers at [Nullable property to entity field, Entity Framework through Code First](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10710393/1115360) would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GROUP JOIN statement indicates that you're attempting a LEFT OUTER JOIN. This is why you're receiving a NULL issue.  By using JOIN for an INNER JOIN, then you won't stumble on this, but it also means that you will only see those items that have values for interest.

```
(FROM a in db.Payments 
Join b in db.InterestCharges ON a.pid Equals b.Pid 
SELECT a, TotalInterestReceived = SUM(b.Interest) 
).toList()
```

It is possible to generate a sub-select which may get the values you're hoping for. The purpose here is that you get all payments, and then basically add in the Interest charges (or 0 if there are none).

```
(From a In db.Payments 
Select a 
, TotalInterestRecieved = (From b in db.InterestCharges 
                           Where b.pid = a.pid
                           select b.Interest).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum() 
).ToList
```

---

**EDIT:**

Another option would be to bypass EF entirely. Build a view in the database and query that view directly rather than attempting to access the underlying data via LINQ.

Most other suggestions I would have would involve iterating through the initial list of "Payments" and populating the values as needed. Which is fine for a small number of "Payments" but that is a O(n) solution.

Comment: The actual query is more complicated hence I can't use   `.defaultifempty(0).sum()`, it has to be `sum(xxxxxx)`.  Also I can't use inner join because the second table may not have records matching the first table, hence it will limit he resultset to what exists in the second table.