# Entity Framework 6 - make Value type properties optional in bulk without making them nullable in domain (code first)

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

So I'm transferring domain classes (**a lot**) to the **postgres** with **EF6**.
Classes can have value type properties, like int and float, and are being transferred to postgres as `NOT NULL`.

I can't make my domain classes properties nullable, as it could break business logic.

I saw this approach - [make props optional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11762360/10021592)

but this means that I have to manually do this in `OnModelCreating` in my `dbcontext` for every class I Have, right?

So, is there any way to make value types (for all my domain classes) nullable in database, like, at initial migration (or any other way in bulk) - so I dont have to manually specify it in `OnModelCreating` for every class I have? Maybe it is possible with some custom convention for it?

tldr - I want to make evey value type property of every class nullable in database with ef6, without making it nullable in domain itself

Thanks!

Comment: [DbModelBuilder.Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbmodelbuilder.properties?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#system-data-entity-dbmodelbuilder-properties) method?

Comment: Could you provide example please? I'm not quite getting what you're talking. You mean modelBuilder.Entity<TableName>().Property(p => p.Name).IsOptional();?

Comment: `modelBuilder.Properties().Where(p => p.Name != "Id").Configure(p => p.IsOptional());` - something like this

Comment: Well, it actually works! You can add your answer here and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [DbModelBuilder.Properties()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbmodelbuilder.properties?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#system-data-entity-dbmodelbuilder-properties) method.

It can be used to set the necessary values for all properties in the `OnModelCreating` method.

```
modelBuilder.Properties().Configure(p => p.IsOptional());
```

However, this will change **all** properties. Of course, there is no need to change the primary keys and some other columns. Therefore, they need to be filtered out.

```
modelBuilder.Properties().Where(p => p.Name != "Id").Configure(p => p.IsOptional());
```

Or something like that:

```
modelBuilder.Properties().Where(p => p.Name.EndsWith("Id")).Configure(p => p.IsOptional());
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try in your `Domain classes` ? [Nullable value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types)

```
public class Book
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public double? Price { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but it is exactly what I don't want to do, as it can break my business logic, so I'm looking for other ways